# mvc3 RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

Why isn't this working. It keeps telling me edit needs a EditStudyModel when I redirect in my Create method. A Redirect should do a get, right?

```
    public ViewResult Create()
    {
        var createStudyModel = new CreateStudyModel();
        return View(createStudyModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateStudyModel createStudyModel)
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO: Send CreateStudyCommand
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { scientificStudyId = new Guid("{1C965285-788A-4B67-9894-3D0D46949F11}") });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(createStudyModel);
        }
    }

    [GET("ScientificStudy/Create/{scientificStudyId}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid scientificStudyId)
    {
        //TODO: Query real model
        var model = new EditStudyModel() {StudyNr = "T01", StudyName = "Test"};
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditStudyModel editStudyModel)
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO: Send UpdateStudyCommand
            return RedirectToAction(""); //TODO: Terug naar Studie lijst
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(editStudyModel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `[GET("ScientificStudy/Create/{scientificStudyId}")]` on your Edit method? because the url in the get should probably be `ScientificStudy/EDIT/{scientificStudyId}` that attribute probably validates the request to make sure it finds the right action.

Comment: I don't recognise the [GET] attribute you have on your Edit action. Is this a custom attribute?

Comment: It's mvc attribute routing. You can get it on Nuget

Comment: I changed the route to         [GET("ScientificStudy/Edit/{scientificStudyId}")]
However it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the error message? A quick sample written up works just fine on my end.

Comment: oooh nasty! Never used attribute based routing but it sounds like a routing configuration issue. You are right RedirecToAction does perform a HTTP GET. Perhaps try installing Glimpse so you can debug the matched route.

Comment: I found the issue. I copy paste my create.cshtml to edit.cshtml
Forgot to change the first line:

@model Website.Models.CreateStudyModel --> to -->
@model Website.Models.EditStudyModel

Comment: Hmmm... How can I mark this issue as answered? Thanks for triggering my attention by thinking with me.

Comment: Write the solution as an answer and then mark that as the answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I copy paste my create.cshtml to edit.cshtml Forgot to change the first line: 
`@model Website.Models.CreateStudyModel` --> to --> `@model Website.Models.EditStudyModel`

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a redirect with a URL as a string, the controller isn't able to parse the GUID and convert it back to a guid object, so it's not able to resolve the correct method signature to use. Change it to:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { scientificStudyId = "{1C965285-788A-4B67-9894-3D0D46949F11}" });
```

and

```
public ActionResult Edit(string scientificStudyId)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? The default model binder is smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, tested it out and it works just fine. You can set the parameter of the Edit method to a Guid and it will parse correctly.